# How to highlight two Menu.Item each in separate component in ANTD with React Router {pathname}

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

I'm trying to create navigation in my app.
I'm using Antd and React Router. I created Menu component which render and returns a complete Menu. There is a attribute on  : selectedKeys and defaultSelectedKeys. So it works fine on my both menu, one navigate through routes like this:

```
/x
/y
/z <- redirect to /z/a
..
```

The second one like this:

```
/z/a
/z/b
/z/c
```

So when I click on /y route Antd selected key will be /y route and highlight menu item, when I click on /z/b the /z/b item in menu will be highlighted, but I want also to highlight the parent route menu item which is /z.
My component to render Menu:

```
const menuItems = routes.map(({ name, path }) => (
    <Menu.Item key={path}>
      <Link to={path}>{name}</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
  ));
  return (
    <Menu
      theme={theme}
      mode={mode}
      {...items}
    >
      { menuItems}
    </Menu>
  );
```

And usage:

- main menu / :

```
<MenuItems routes={mainRoutes}  />
```

- sub menu /z :

```
<MenuItems routes={subRoutes}  />
```

Main and sub routes implementation:

```
const mainRoutes= [
 {
    path: '/x',
    name: 'x',
    component: ...,
  },  {
    path: '/y',
    name: 'y',
    component: ...,
  },
  {
    path: '/z',
    name: 'z',
    component: ...,
  },
];
const subRoutes = [
  {
    path: /z/a.,
    name: 'z a',
    component: ...,
  },
  {
    path: /z/b,
    name: 'z b',
    component: ...,
  },
 
];
```

Comment: Please also share how you have declared `mainRoutes` & `subRoutes`?

Comment: @bonnopc added routes settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectedKeys` prop to specify your associated routes in `Menu` component of Ant Design. Visit [here](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu) for more info.

```js
// ...
function SideBar(){
   // ...
   const location = useLocation();

   const getAssociatedPaths = () => {
       if(mainRoutes.find(route => route.path === location.pathname)){
           return null; // matched with main route
       }
       
       const firstSlug = location?.pathname.split("/")[0];
       const matchedMainRoute = mainRoutes.find(route => route.path.slice(1) === firstSlug);

       if(matchedMainRoute) return [ matchedMainRoute.path, location.pathname ];

       return null;
   }

   return (
       <Menu
           theme={theme}
           mode={mode}
           selectedKeys={getAssociatedPaths()}
           {...items}
       >
           { menuItems}
       </Menu>
   );

}
```

But, it would be a good approach if you declare your sub-routes in your `mainRoutes`. Thus you can easily recognize your parent route/path.

Comment: Working well! Thanks, I have to learn more about use-cases of attributes :)